# ScrollView for TabLayout with VIewPager

Tags: android

I need to scroll the `TabLayout`, but when I write this code, the `TabLayout` is invisible.

How can I edit this code for the scrolling text in items of `TabLayout`?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/book_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/book_tab_layout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/book_description_tab_item"
                android:text="@string/book_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/book_reviews_tab_item"
                android:text="@string/book_reviews"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/book_related_titles_tab_item"
                android:text="@string/book_related_titles"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting ScrollViews width to android:layout_width="match_parent"?

Comment: yes, i try all width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `android.support.v7.widget.NestedScrollView` in place of ScrollView.
with app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Thanx  a lot dear

Comment: typo in the code at "behaviour" -> behavior. Also the solution doesn't work for me.